# Cesium get coordinates from Entity loaded from KML

Tags: javascript, kml, cesiumjs

I am trying to draw an arrowhead for each point in a kml file. For this I plan to fetch coordinates for each point by getById. So far I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined (on line 14)
```

Here is my code:

```
var src = Cesium.KmlDataSource.load('../../My_KML/plots.kml', options);
viewer.dataSources.add(src).then(function(data) {viewer.flyTo(data);});

//-------------------********--------------**********-----------------//
var point = viewer.entities.getById('geom_20102');

var entities = viewer.entities;

 var cartographicPosition = Cesium.Cartographic.fromCartesian(point.position.getValue(Cesium.JulianDate.now()));
            var latitude = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographicPosition.latitude);
            var longitude = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographicPosition.longitude);

var line1 = entities.add({
    polyline : {
        positions : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights([longitude, latitude, 360, longitude + 1, latitude + 1, 400]),
        width : 10,
        followSurface : false,
        material : new Cesium.PolylineArrowMaterialProperty(Cesium.Color.BLUE)
    }
});
```

I have specified the element with id 'geom_20102' as a linestring wrapped around by a placemark in the kml. Also I would like to know which id to specify as both placemark and linestring have an id. Or am I confusing kml id with entity id?

I am new to Cesium.Js and I followed this example partially:
[Cesium Workshop](http://52.4.31.236/tutorials/Cesium-Workshop/)

KML snippet:

```
 <Placemark id="feat_20125">
        <name>874</name>
        <styleUrl>#stylesel_20102</styleUrl>
        <LineString id="geom_20102">
            <coordinates>104.99108,10.4118,247.3 72.991075,26.25412,247.6</coordinates>
            <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
```

Comment: Did you check if var point returned from getById() is null?

Comment: Yes it is returning undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are going on here.

First, the [Cesium.KmlDataSource.load()](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/KmlDataSource.html) function returns a JavaScript "Promise" which represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation. At the time the viewer.entities is referenced in the code, the KML file has not yet loaded so the collection in *viewer.entities* is empty and calling getById() on it will return `undefined`. You should only access the viewer.entities or data.entities after the async Promise is completed and the "then" callback is invoked. Only at that time are the entities populated.

```
var src = Cesium.KmlDataSource.load('../../My_KML/plots.kml', options);
viewer.dataSources.add(src).then(function(data) {
    
    var entities = data.entities;
    console.log("f=" + entities.getById('feat_20125')); // f=[object Object]
    console.log("g=" + entities.getById('geom_20102')); // undefined

    viewer.flyTo(data);
});
```

Next, notice that the 'feat_20125' returns an object but the 'geom_20102' is not found. Only the "id" on the placemarks are populated when KML is converted into Cesium entities. Ids on any other KML element are discarded.

Comment: I need to access entities generated only through KML, not all. Currently I'm parsing though entitycollection array. That is clearly wrong, as not all entities are placemarks. How do I go about it?

Comment: Parsing through entitycollection gives you access to the converted placemarks. If you need access to the complete KML then you would need to parse the KML using an XML parser or another kml parser such as GeoXML3. You could always add the extra metadata you need from the KML to ExtendedData which will be imported into the Cesium entities.

Comment: No let me clarify. Parsing through entitycollection does give me converted placemarks. But there are some entities which are not placemarks (like ellipses, or polylines). I need a way to sift through only placemarks. Eg: entities.values[] array is of size 1035 and only entities 1000 to 1034 are placemarks. Also, are things like ExtendedData from KML stored in entities.description? What is the correspondence between KML and Entity? Pls correct if I'm conceptually wrong

Comment: The ExtendedData in KML features are stored in the Cesium entity [properties](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Entity.html) field.

Comment: Should this be moved to another question (i mean parsing through entities one)?

Comment: Yes, parsing the entities is a separate but related question.